# Store returned linux command value into python variable

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I won't lie I know this is a very easily answered question, I'm just having trouble with the documentation and given how specific I feel this is it is a little hard to find solutions online.

I'm running **Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi** and are attempting to write a **python script** that operates with the signal strength of a Bluetooth connection. In the Linux command line, if I input `hcitool rssi 14:C8:9B:92:C2:05` it will return `RSSI return value: 12`. What I'm trying to do is **store this value in a python variable** in the script.

In my script I have tried both importing os, and importing subprocess modules based of the documentation I have seen online, and have tried these solutions:

```
var = os.system('hcitool rssi 14:C8:9B:92:C2:05')
```

```
def find_dist():
        return(os.system('hcitool rssi 14:C8:9B:92:C2:05'))
var=find_dist()
```

```
var = subprocess.call('hcitool rssi 14:C8:9B:92:C2:05', shell = true)
```

The os module will simply output the regular `RSSI return value: 12` and print 0 for all variable values, and the subprocess module I can't really figure out the proper syntax to. I know this may seem simple, but given the specific nature I'm having trouble finding the proper documentation~

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is with `subprocess.run` which will capture the output so you can look at it later.  Here's the most simple example to get a feel for how it works:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(['echo', 'hi'], capture_output=True)
print(result.stdout)
```

Which will print the expected `hi` as the output.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately when I first try your example I receive an error:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'
This was before I tried to amend it to my particular program~

Comment: Is this on windows by chance?  that would be the one place that I think may not work, as windows isn't a posix compliant architecture.

Comment: Oh, wait you said raspberrian...  It should definitely work there.